# Text editor internal text storage: optimal chunk size?

Tags: performance, text, data-structures, x86, buffer

It seems obvious that when implementing a general-purpose text editor (by general purpose I mean for example that it does not have to be able to handle huge files (over 100-200 MB (which is still a lot, and is more like an extreme example of "general case")), it is not feasible to just store the text in one continuous long buffer, because performance is going to suck on insertions/deletions.

While there are a number of ways to tackle this, they all revolve around the fact that you have to split the text up into chunks, and so my question is: considering today's computer power, what would be the optimal chunk size? What is the actual size of a text buffer that is practically starts to get too big for storing in a simple continuous buffer? How fast are contemporary computers at moving big chunks of bytes around?
(For the sake of clarity let's just say that gap buffers can't be used, each chunk will be a simple continuous array.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical consumer system can achieve between 10 and 30 GB/s of raw memory throughput on DDR3 memory. That is kind of a base number.

From my experience I think it is safe to assume that you will see no problem in Java to achieve around 100 MB of memory operations per second (C++ probably can do 4-8 times as much). From that it would seem that with a buffer size of 64kb you could go to something like 2^10 operations per second and still would be fine.

Answer (score 3):

In Eclipse almost all editors are implemented using `GapTextStore`, so they only rely on a single buffer with a single gab.

The interesting part of the JaveDoc for `GapTextStore` states:

> Implements a gap managing text store. The gap text store relies on the assumption that consecutive changes to a document are co-located. The start of the gap is always moved to the location of the last change.
>
> Performance: Typing-style changes perform in constant time unless re-allocation becomes necessary. Generally, a change that does not cause re-allocation will cause at most one arraycopy operation of a length of about d, where d is the distance from the previous change. Let a(x) be the algorithmic performance of an arraycopy operation of the length x, then such a change then performs in O(a(x)), get(int, length) performs in O(a(length)), get(int) in O(1).
>
> How frequently the array needs re-allocation is controlled by the constructor parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on the [data structure known as a "rope"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28computer_science%29) (rope being a kind of heavyweight string of course).  The original [SGI STL had them](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Rope.html) as well as strings, and while they didn't make it into the C++ Standard Library, [Gnu has them as an extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.3/a00223.html).

Note that a "chunk size" doesn't appear as such in the implementation ([notes](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/ropeimpl.html)), which is much more about doing things in a lazy, functional way.

Comment: Well like I wrote, there are number of data structures that can handle this efficiently, and they all (yes, ropes too) have a "chunk size" in their implementations. The only other alternative is to make each rope segment contain only a single character/element, and I can't imagine any implementation being that inefficient. Of course, when you take an existing library, you don't think about these details. But I wanted to know what is the optimal chunk size for own low level implementation.

Comment: Just to clarify, it's possible that there isn't a "set" leaf size in the rope, and it's all dynamic, but ultimately the rope will have to rebalance, and there will be some memory movement, reallocations, etc. In those contexts the chunk size is as important.